Bison: howto handle optional ';' after statement
I have a probably common bison grammar problem:
Statements are normally separated by ';'. However I want the exception of code blocks '{' '}' without the requirement to terminate with a ';'.
As an example:
fun a() {
}
1+1; 2+2;

The problem now is that when I allow lambdas as part of expressions F=fun(){} then the function definition grammar is the primary inside an expression, but these require a ';' .
Is there some smart way to define the grammar so that a toplevel function definition doesn't require ';'
I am thinking about whether I can change the behaviour of flex scanner to return a '\n' at the end of a block '{ ... }' definition if one exist and accept that as a statement delimiter. Is that possible?
how do I change the flex lexer state from bison and only for the period of when the end of a statement block is parsed ?
Here is the example:
Makefile:
all:
    bison -rall -o parse.c n.y
    flex -o scan.c n.l
    gcc  -g -c parse.c -o parse.o
    gcc  -g -c scan.c -o scan.o
    gcc  -g -c n.c -o n.o
    gcc  -g scan.o parse.o n.o -lc -o n.exe
    ./n.exe test.txt

n.y:
%{
#define YYDEBUG 1

%}

%code requires {

extern enum yytokentype yylex();
  extern void yyerror(const char* errmsg);
  extern void yyerrorf(const char* format, ...);

}

%expect 0
//          %define api.pure
//          %locations
%define parse.trace
%verbose
%header
%define parse.error verbose


%token  FUNC

%token  ID NUM

%left  '+'

%%
%start unit;

unit: stmts

stmts:
        stmt                       {}
    |   stmts  stmt                {}

stmt:
        expr ';'                   {}
    ;

expr:       expr '+' expr              {}
    |   primary                    {}
    ;

primary:
        NUM                        {}
    |   ID                         {}
    |   FUNC '('  ')' '{' stmts  '}'       {}
    |   FUNC ID '('  ')' '{' stmts { } '}' {}
    ;

%%

void yyerror(const char* errmsg)
{
  printf("%s",errmsg);
}

n.l
%option noyywrap nounput noinput batch debug
%x l8 retnl

%{

#include "parse.h"

%}

id    [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z_0-9]*
int   [0-9]+
blank [ \t\r]

%%

[\n]        { }
[ \t]       { }
[#][^\n]*   { }

fun    { return FUNC;   }

"{"     {return '{';}
"}"     {return '}';}
"("     {return '(';}
")"     {return ')';}
"+"     {return '+';}
";"     {return ';';}

{id}        {return ID; }
{int}       {return NUM; }

%%

n.c:
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include "parse.h"

#define fail(fmt, ...) do { printf(fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__); exit(1); } while(0)

static void
readin(char *fname)
{
  struct stat st;
  int fd;
  char *ptr, *p, *pend;

  fd = open(fname, O_RDONLY, 0);
  if (fd < 0) fail("fail open %s", fname);

  if (fstat(fd, &st) < 0) fail("fail sta %s", fname);
  if (!S_ISREG(st.st_mode)) {
    fail("fail %s is not a regular file", fname);
  }
  p = ptr = (char *)malloc(st.st_size+1);
  if (read(fd, ptr, st.st_size) != st.st_size) {

  }
  ptr[st.st_size] = 0;

  extern void * yy_scan_string (const char * yystr );
  yy_scan_string( ptr );

  yydebug=1;
  yyparse();

}

/* 8< --- main --- */

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  if (argc >= 1) {
    readin(argv[1]);
  }
  return 0;
}

Here is the testfile:
fun a() {
 1;
};
1+1;1+fun(){3;};2+2;

Here is the testfile that I would like to accept.
it has ';' after the function block removed:
fun a() {
 1;
}
1+1;1+fun(){3;};2+2;


You forgot to post your attempt to solve this problem.

You have not shown any details of your grammar. If you added a rule that allowed a lambda in an expression and that caused a problem with the grammar, bison would show a message. You should show at least a reduced/simplified grammar that reproduces that message and the message, or otherwise explain what issue arises in the grammar clearly enough that other people can reproduce it.

@ScottHunter: That is not a requirement for this type of problem.

@EricPostpischil: Is there some rule that it can't be asked for?

@ScottHunter: You did not ask for it. You alleged the author “forgot” to post it, which is a criticism of the person, not a request for information.

I appended a testgrammar.

If I take the |   FUNC ID '('  ')' '{' stmts { } '}' {} line out of primary and insert it in stmt, I get a grammar that accepts both of your test cases.

Some caveats for my testing: You did not supply a parse.h or show how it is generated, so I created one (and manually inserted into it definitions for FUNC, ID, and NUM as 258, 259, and 260 to match the values in parse.c and parse.output). My version of bison (2.3, shipped with Apple’s tools) does not like %code (so I moved the code in that into the preceding %{) or %define or %header (so I suppressed those by marking them as comments). Then everything compiled and ran.

@EricPostpischil:  want to generate lambdas as first class objects. So I need to have FUNC inside the expression. (I use bison 3.8.2)

It seems to work with the hack:
n.l
%option noyywrap nounput noinput batch debug
%x l8 retnl

%{

#include "parse.h"

%}


id    [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z_0-9]*
int   [0-9]+
blank [ \t\r]

%%

<INITIAL>.|\n       {BEGIN l8; yyless(0); }

<retnl>[\n]           {return '\n';}
<l8>[\n]              { }
<l8,retnl>[ \t]       { }
<l8,retnl>[#][^\n]*   { }

<l8,retnl>fun         { return FUNC;   }

<l8,retnl>"{"       {return '{';}
<l8,retnl>"}"       {return '}';}
<l8,retnl>"("       {return '(';}
<l8,retnl>")"       {return ')';}
<l8,retnl>"+"       {return '+';}
<l8,retnl>";"       {return ';';}

<l8,retnl>{id}        {return ID; }
<l8,retnl>{int}       {return NUM; }

%%

I define 2 states l8 and retnl.  l8 will swollow '\n' and retnl will return '\n'.
Now in the grammar I do:
n.y:
%{
#define YYDEBUG 1

%}

%code requires {


extern int yy_start;
#define retnl 2

extern enum yytokentype yylex();
  extern void yyerror(const char* errmsg);
  extern void yyerrorf(const char* format, ...);

}

%expect 0
//          %define api.pure
//          %locations
%define parse.trace
%verbose
%header
%define parse.error verbose


%token  FUNC

%token  ID NUM

%left  '+'

%%
%start unit;

unit: stmts

stmts:
        stmt                       {}
    |   stmts  stmt                {}

stmt:
        expr D                     { yy_start = 1 + 2 * 1 /*state:l8*/; }
    ;

D:      ';'
    |   '\n'
    ;


expr:       expr '+' expr              {}
    |   primary                    {}
    ;

primary:
        NUM                        {}
    |   ID                         {}
    |   FUNC     '(' ')' '{' stmts { yy_start = 1 + 2 * 2 /*state:retnl*/; } '}' { }
    |   FUNC ID '('  ')' '{' stmts { yy_start = 1 + 2 * 2 /*state:retnl*/; } '}' {}
    ;

%%

void yyerror(const char* errmsg)
{
  printf("%s",errmsg);
}

To be able to access yy_start i need to add
sed -i -e 's/static int yy_start/int yy_start/' scan.c

in Makefile:
all:
    bison -rall -o parse.c n.y
    flex -o scan.c n.l
    sed -i -e 's/static int yy_start/int yy_start/' scan.c
    gcc  -g -c parse.c -o parse.o
    gcc  -g -c scan.c -o scan.o
    gcc  -g -c n.c -o n.o
    gcc  -g scan.o parse.o n.o -lc -o n.exe
    ./n.exe test.txt

The 2 lines
yy_start = 1 + 2 * 1  /*state:l8*/ and yy_start = 1 + 2 * 2  /*state:retnl*/ come from the definition of BEGIN(l8) and BEGIN(retnl) if they would be used inside the flex grammar.
Does anybody know a more standard way of achieving this?
